# SQL update from one table to another based on column match on Apache Derby

Tags: sql, sql-update, derby

N.B. I'm looking for a solution working on Apache Derby

I have two sql tables. The first, called `links`, contains links of the form

```
SOURCE    | TARGET
1234      | 456
15        | 625
...       | ...
```

where the integers here are the ids of the objects being linked. The second table, called `redir`, contains redirection links:

```
ID        | REDIRTARGET
456       | 521
198       | 140
...       | ...
```

If the `target` of a link is in the `id` column of `redir`, then it must be redirected to the object of id `redirtarget`.

Now, I would like to update my `links` table by replacing all targets which are in the `id` column of `redir` by the associated `redirtarget`.

For example, given the two tables above (without ellipses), the update instruction would replace 456 with 521 in the `target` column of `links`.

I haven't been able to find a working instruction on my own. I've tried things like

```
UPDATE links,redir SET target=redirtarget WHERE id=target
```

but that won't compile (specifically, derby points out at the comma between `UPDATE` and `SET`). Help anybody ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify multiple tables in an UPDATE list.

If ID in the redir table is unique, you should be able do something like this:

```
update links
  set target = (select redirtarget 
                from redir
                where redir.id = links.target)
where exists (select *
              from redir
              where redir.id = links.target);
```

The `where` condition ensures that only rows in `links` are updated where there is actually a match in the `redir` table.